# Bazel repository rule- Can I access something like Java's "os.arch"?

Tags: bazel

I need to write a Bazel repository rule which downloads mysql binaries according to the required version, to the operating system and the architecture.

I'll get the required version from the user, the operating system from `repository_os.name` but I'm not sure how I can access the architecture?

The current non-hermetic code uses `os.arch` as a good enough heuristic (yes I know it's not precise).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the architecture, except asking for `uname -m` using `repository_ctx.execute`. You can also make it work on Windows by executing a different command depending on `repository_ctx.os.name` (which is the same as `os.name` from the JVM so if it contains `win` you can execute the Windows command). If you think this is needed, please file a feature request on https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new

Comment: Thanks! It's actually not the same as `os.arch` as it returns the bit of the jvm runtime and not the OS. Can you maybe add that clarification to your answer so I'll accept it? Essentially for me I might just have the luxury of assuming 64 bit architectures and be done with it.

Comment: How do you get access to the `repository_ctx` object?

Answer (score 0):

The host platform's CPU architecture and operating system name are accessible via [repository_ctx.os](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repository_ctx#os). The attribute is a [repository_os](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repository_os) struct with [arch](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repository_os#arch) and [name](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repository_os#name).